# prime number (diophantine equation)

Tags: number-theory

143 is semi prime number. 143 to power any odd is congruent to 3 mod 4 and 143 to power any even is congruent to 1 mod 4. Is it correct to write this way?

Comment: Sure....may be simpler to write $143\equiv -1 \pmod 4\implies 143^n\equiv (-1)^n\pmod 4$.

Comment: Why do you have "Diophantine equation" in the title? I only see modulo $4$ calculation.